# forward all traffic to another machine using reverse ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, site-to-site-vpn, tunneling

I have the following scenario

```
                                                                                                                  
               Local Network                     |                          Global Network                        
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |                                                                
+------------+              +-----------+        |               +----------+                   +----------------+
|   client A | -----------> |  server A | <--------------------> | server B | --------------->  | Global Network |
+------------+              +-----------+        |               +----------+                   +----------------+
                                                 |                                                                
                                                 |
```

The challenge ahead:

Transfer all traffic from `server A` to `server B`. Since all tunnel protocols are closed in `server A`, I thought reverse ssh is a good option.

I use the following command for making reverse ssh:
`ssh -fNT -R 4000:localhost:22 ubuntu@62.45.xx.xx -i <private-key>`

Now on `server A` I can see that port `4000` is opened.
but I don't know how to transfer the traffic as a whole to `server B`

Comment: *"Since all tunnel protocols are closed in server A, I thought reverse ssh is a good option."*  - Generally there is a policy/reason  for such things and (regardless of your opinions and your inconvenience) circumventing your corporate policy is usually *not* the *good* option. Whatever good intentions you have, what you're actually attempting  is often considered [data exfiltration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_exfiltration) ... - And practically speaking, forwarding specific protocol and targeted traffic may be easier.

Comment: Yes, or in a situation where everything has been filtered for you
I am not referring to a specific country

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is to create a tun interface and setup routing appropriately. As you see below from ssh man the following commandline argument is available.

> -w local_tun[:remote_tun]
> Requests tunnel device forwarding with the specified tun(4) devices between >the client (local_tun) and the server (remote_tun).
> The devices may be specified by numerical ID or the keyword “any”, which >uses the next available tunnel device. If remote_tun is not specified, it >defaults to “any”. See also the Tunnel and TunnelDevice directives in >ssh_config(5).

> If the Tunnel directive is unset, it will be set to the default tunnel >mode, which is “point-to-point”. If a different Tunnel forwarding mode it >desired, then it should be specified before -w.

This answer provides more details.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525217/create-network-interface-from-ssh-tunnel